# Erro em left join linq - DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, linq

Tenho o seguinte método:

Porém, quando executo a consulta no linq, utilizando o left join recebo a seguinte mensagem :

> DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("findAll")]
    public HttpResponseMessage findAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var tamanho = (from bc in bdprincipalEntities.tamanho
                           join c in bdprincipalEntities.fornecedor on bc.for_codigo
                           equals c.For_codigo into c_c
                           from c in c_c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           join d in bdprincipalEntities.GrupoProduto on bc.GrupoProduto_Codigo
                           equals d.GrupoProduto_Codigo into d_bc
                           from d in d_bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new
                           {
                               Tam_codigo = bc.Tam_codigo,
                               Tam_descricao = bc.Tam_descricao,
                               GrupoProduto_Descricao = d.GrupoProduto_Descricao,
                               For_Nome = c.For_Nome,
                               for_codigo = bc.for_codigo,
                               tam_CodFor = bc.tam_CodFor,
                               Emp_codigo = bc.Emp_codigo,
                               Tam_situacao = bc.Tam_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO"

                          }).ToList();

            result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tamanho));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Os campos que estou comparando são do tipo int:

```
public Nullable<int> for_codigo { get; set; } //Da tabela tamanho
public int For_codigo { get; set; } // Da tabela fornecedor

public Nullable<int> GrupoProduto_Codigo { get; set; } // Da tabela Tamanho
public int GrupoProduto_Codigo { get; set; } // Da tabela Grupo de Produto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que a causa do problema da sua `query` está nas propriedades que são `Nullable types`.

Um `int nullable` pode receber receber um `int`, porém no trecho do seu `select new {}` você está fazendo o inverso, passando um `nullable` para um `int type` e isto não é correto.

Note que `bc.for_codigo` representa:

```
public public Nullable<int> for_codigo { get; set; } //Da tabela tamanho
```

Você está atribuindo à este `nullable for_cordigo` que é um `int type` comum, será necessário ajuste na query para inverter ou mudar as propriedades caso seja possível.

Também precisa avaliar o trecho abaixo onde é feito o `join`, pois pode estar ocorrendo o mesmo erro citado acima:

```
join c in bdprincipalEntities.fornecedor on bc.for_codigo
equals c.For_codigo into c_c
```

Veja esta definição para os `Nullables types`:

> Os tipos que permitem valor nulo têm as seguintes características: Os
>   tipos que permitem valor nulo representam variáveis de tipo de valor
>   que podem ser atribuídas ao valor null. Você não pode criar um tipo
>   que permite valor nulo com base em um tipo de referência. (Os tipos de
>   referência já dão suporte ao valor null.)

Caso queira saber mais veja o guia completo aqui: [Tipos que permitem valor nulo (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Comment: Entendi, porém mesmo alterando as propriedades acontece o mesmo erro

Comment: Estranho...sugiro que faça uma `query` isolada somente com o `left join` que está com problema., jogando o resultado em uma nova lista, para isolar e poder alisar melhor, às vezes pode ser até outra coisa que está causando o erro.

Comment: Irei fazer, só terminar uma coisa, mas estava analisando, os nomes não são exatamente iguais, pode ser isso?  for_codigo e For_codigo